# How do I wait for particular response without neglecting other responses using select in c sockets?

Tags: c, sockets, select

I have a single client program where I need to `send` a request and timed wait for the corresponding `response`. But I should be receiving all other responses even if it is `waiting or not`.

My pseudocode:

Recv Section:

```
struct timeval timeout = {
     .tv_sec = 5,
     .tv_usec = 0
};

while (1) {
   ret = select(maxfd + 1, &rdfd, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
   if (ret == 0) {
       fprintf(stderr, "No response for request\n");
       return;
   }

   ret = recvfrom(.buf..);

   struct standard_msg *std_msg = buf;

   switch(std_msg->type) {
        case TYPE_1: 
            if expecting response for TYPE_1
            read and retun from here;
            else loop until timeout
        case TYPE_2:
            if expecting response for TYPE_2
            read and return from here
            else loop until timeout
        default:
            print buf
   }
}
```

Send Section:

```
while(1) {
   struct timeval timeout = {
      .tv_sec = 50,
      .tv_usec = 0
   }
   select(1, NULL, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
   send_a_packet_wait_for_ITS_response(); //which will call the recv_secion
}
```

The `send` happens by reading the contents of file every `50` secs. Lets say if a packet is sent got reply right back, now I will be waiting for  `50` secs to send other packet. During this time I cannot `read` any packet that is received. And if the file reaches `EOF` there is nothing to send and now also I cannot `read` any packet.

So here I need to continuously listen to all packets and also listen for a particular packet. Is it possible to run a `listen` code for all other packets and `listen` code for particular packets? How do I solve this problem?

My intention is to get reply for a particular request within a configured timeout, without losing other packets.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question embodies a contradiction in terms. Either you're waiting for a particular response or you're processing whatever responses arrive. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: You can do a narrow select, even one just waiting for the timeout to complete.  But as has been said, you have contradictory targets on this problem... If you want to be notified on any event, do a wider select, if you want to be notified on a narrow set of events, do a narrow select.

Answer (score -1):

No interpretation of the payload itself (i.e. OSI layer 5..7) is done by the OS when you read from a socket. This means all application layer logic like this has to be done in the application itself. Which means that you need to read each packet even if you don't need it know, in which case you could just put it in some application specific buffer for later use.